# simple random sampling example in R

Tags: r

I am looking to conduct a simple random sample using the iris data set, sorted by species and sepal.length, and from this list randomly selecting 20 rows. I save this as a new data frame iris.new. I then set a seed to reproduce the results. When I subset the data frame to the randomly sampled rows, however, there are different row numbers returned than from the sample function. Why is this occurring?

```
#---draw from Iris data set, 20 random rows, ordered by species, sepal.length flower
      summary(iris)
      iris.new <- iris[order(iris$Species, iris$Sepal.Length), ]
    #---set seed
      set.seed(60900921)
    
    #---random sample 20 
      iris.sample <-sample(1:nrow(iris.new), 20)
      iris.sample
    
    #---save as data set 
      iris.sample.df <-iris.new[iris.sample, ]
      iris.sample.df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you arrange the data by `Species` and `Sepal.Length`, the row numbers
are shuffled around. When you then use the `iris.sample` to index `iris.new`
the row indices point to different row numbers/names.

Look at iris.new to see that the row numbers are shuffled around.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(60900921)

iris.new <- 
  iris[order(iris$Species, iris$Sepal.Length),] 
iris.new |> 
  head()
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
#> 9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 39          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 43          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 42          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
#> 4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa

# sample 20 row indices
iris.sample <- sample(1:nrow(iris.new), 20)
iris.sample
#>  [1]  52  99 122  10  95 134  76   8  59   3 137  79  23 113 101   9  36 104  33
#> [20]  94
```

Now, if you add new row numbers to iris.new, you’ll see that these align
with the random row indices in `iris.sample`.

```r
iris.new$new_row_numbers <- 1:nrow(iris.new)

# obtain rows with random row indices
iris.sample.df <- iris.new[iris.sample,]

iris.sample.df |> 
  select(new_row_numbers, everything())
#>     new_row_numbers Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 61               52          5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0
#> 53               99          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5
#> 129             122          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.1
#> 3                10          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
#> 66               95          6.7         3.1          4.4         1.4
#> 113             134          6.8         3.0          5.5         2.1
#> 71               76          5.9         3.2          4.8         1.8
#> 23                8          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2
#> 82               59          5.5         2.4          3.7         1.0
#> 39                3          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2
#> 140             137          6.9         3.1          5.4         2.1
#> 84               79          6.0         2.7          5.1         1.6
#> 26               23          5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2
#> 149             113          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3
#> 107             101          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7
#> 48                9          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2
#> 47               36          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2
#> 102             104          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9
#> 24               33          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5
#> 76               94          6.6         3.0          4.4         1.4
#>        Species
#> 61  versicolor
#> 53  versicolor
#> 129  virginica
#> 3       setosa
#> 66  versicolor
#> 113  virginica
#> 71  versicolor
#> 23      setosa
#> 82  versicolor
#> 39      setosa
#> 140  virginica
#> 84  versicolor
#> 26      setosa
#> 149  virginica
#> 107  virginica
#> 48      setosa
#> 47      setosa
#> 102  virginica
#> 24      setosa
#> 76  versicolor
```

You can also use `dplyr::slice_sample()` to obtain a random sample:

```r
iris_sample <-
  iris |>
  slice_sample(n = 20)

iris_sample
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 1           6.3         2.3          4.4         1.3 versicolor
#> 2           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1     setosa
#> 3           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 4           5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4     setosa
#> 5           5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 6           4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> 7           6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5  virginica
#> 8           6.0         2.2          4.0         1.0 versicolor
#> 9           6.1         3.0          4.9         1.8  virginica
#> 10          5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 11          5.7         2.5          5.0         2.0  virginica
#> 12          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0  virginica
#> 13          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> 14          6.9         3.1          5.4         2.1  virginica
#> 15          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#> 16          5.1         2.5          3.0         1.1 versicolor
#> 17          5.8         2.7          3.9         1.2 versicolor
#> 18          5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2     setosa
#> 19          5.6         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 20          5.8         2.8          5.1         2.4  virginica
```